# Ionic 2 - get list items in current view

Tags: angular, scroll, ionic2

I have a `ion-list` with multiple items, inside `ion-content`. Whenever I scroll, I want to get an array with the items that are currently inside the view and do something to them (like changing css class). Is there any way I can achieve this?
I've tried the following:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.content.ionScroll.subscribe(($event: any) => {
        let elements = this.content.getScrollElement().getElementsByClassName('myCssClass');
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            let classes = elements[i].classList;
            classes.remove('myCssClass');
        }  
    });
 }
```

But this returns me all the elements with the specified class, not those that are in the scroll view.